# Ошибка при работе с php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть проблема с системой авторизации на языке php.

Код файла авторизации такой :

```
<?php
$login = trim($_POST['login']);
$password = $_POST['pas'];

$password = md5($password.'123');

$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','mysqli');

$result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$login' AND `password` = '$password' ");

$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

if(count($user) == 0) {
    echo 'error';
    exit();

}

$mysql->close();
```

?>
.

И после авторизации, следующая ошибка:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in W:\domains\signup.com\auth.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in W:\domains\signup.com\auth.php on line 11.
Кто знает, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Comment: $user = $result->fetch_assoc(); замените на  $user 
 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: после этого выдает 2 другие ошибки: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in W:\domains\signup.com\auth.php on line 11

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in W:\domains\signup.com\auth.php on line 13
error

Comment: Pavel, спасибо вам огромное за решение!

Comment: не за что. с новыми ошибками разобрались?

Comment: Да спасибо.....